# В опере - на балете

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему мы говорим "побывал В опере", но "сходит НА балет"?

Answer (score 1):

Употребление предлога **В** в пространственном значении связано с представлением об ограниченном пространстве, при отсутствии этого значения употребляется предлог **НА** (Розенталь).

Предлоги **В** и **НА** с пространственной семантикой могут быть синонимичными. В некоторых случаях закрепляется один из синонимических предлогов: *работать в фотостудии – работать на киностудии*. Иногда сказывается исторически сложившаяся традиция; ср.: *в деревне – на хуторе*. Думаю, с *оперой* и *балетом* тот же случай: так сложилось исторически.

Могу лишь высказать свои соображения о том, почему так получилось. И опера, и балет - спектакли, представления, часто идущие на одной и той же сцене. Поэтому говорить о каких-то смысловых различиях в употреблении предлогов не совсем правильно. С обоими существительными логично было бы употреблять предлог НА. Как мне кажется, выражение *побывать в опере* закрепилось в языке из-за того, что есть оперный театр: *побывать в оперном театре > побывать в опере* (метонимический перенос). С *балетом* такого не происходит, поскольку балетных театров не наблюдается. Как правило, балетные представления ставятся на сцене оперных театров.

Comment: Как это балетных театров не наблюдается? Вообще-то театры называются театрами "оперы и балета".